# python: How to calculate mean for multiple columns from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I would like to create a new columns in the data frame containing mean values of 3 columns.
This is how I've done it. Anyone could suggest me a more elegant way?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (10, 6)), columns = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 
                                                                         'b1', 'b2', 'b3']])
df['mean_a'] = df[['a1', 'a2', 'a3']].mean(axis=1).astype(int)
df['mean_d'] = df[['b1', 'b2', 'b3']].mean(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you don't want to type out all those column names then you could do something like this:

```
df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).mean().astype(int).add_prefix('mean_'))
```

Output:

```
   a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3  mean_a  mean_b
0  44  47  64  67  67   9      51      47
1  83  21  36  87  70  88      46      81
2  88  12  58  65  39  87      52      63
3  46  88  81  37  25  77      71      46
4  72   9  20  80  69  79      33      76
5  47  64  82  99  88  49      64      78
6  29  19  19  14  39  32      22      28
7  65   9  57  32  31  74      43      45
8  23  35  75  55  28  34      44      39
9   0   0  36  53   5  38      12      32
```

Comment: Don't mix up coding and encrypting ...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your solution. 'Elegance' is not a criteria in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), see

```
import this
```

*Explicit is better than implicit.

Sparse is better than dense.

Readability counts.

...*

Comment: In the real data I have quite a lot of the columns. That's the reason why I am looking for more automated solution.

Comment: So you want to mix all the means with the observations in one big dataframe? That's even worse and a typical beginner misconception to take a dataframe for an Excel spreadsheet ...

Comment: I need to prepare nice output excel spreadsheets for my boss. This is the only way he wants to see the data. Not really my choice. Also I can't control the way other softwares are exporting data.